How can I access right and left hands of piano MIDI track separately with python?
I'm exploring MIDI files with Python and MuseScore. When I open a MIDI file from this dataset:  PiJAMA dataset, https://zenodo.org/records/8354955, on MuseScore, I see that the piano track is automatically split into two staves: right and left hands. However when I print the MIDI file tracks in Python with mido or prettymidi there is only one track with notes on it. My question is, how does MuseScore know which notes correspond to which hand if there seems to be nothing indicating it in the MIDI file? I would like to have access to the notes of each hand separately in Python, just like in MuseScore, so I can do some machine learning experiments.
I tried printing the tracks with mido and prettymidi. Track 0 has no notes on it, just defines the time signature and other global constants like ticks per beat. Track 1 has all the notes on it, but there seems to be nothing which notes correspond to what hand, yet I see that MuseScore recognizes it as a piano track with right and left hands separated. I know that it is an Acoustic Grand Piano track because of the program_change message. Maybe there some piece of information I canretrieve with mido that tells which notes correspond to what hand?

The MIDI file doesn't contain the data at all. MuseScore is synthesizing/inferring; you would need to implement comparable logic yourself.

Do you have any idea what this logic might be?

The canonical location is MuseScore's source. There's a very brief description in the docs at https://musescore.org/en/handbook/3/midi-import (search for "split staff"), but really, read the fine source. Off-site resource requests (finding documentation/source/etc) are categorically outside our scope.
